# Did Edward Snowden leak documents on aliens?

Tags: united-states, aliens, wikileaks

I by chance found a site claiming that Edward Snowden had leaked documents which proved something to do with aliens and the US government knowing about them and possibly even having some further connection to them. I searched around a bit and couldn't find a good example of a website which doesn't sound completely mad, but if you go [to a search like this](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Edward%20Snowden%20alien%20leak) or similar you will see what I mean. The ones which give a source seem to go back [to this Fox News article](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9UihMavjguY) on something an Iranian news source claimed.

Which is thought to be more likely political against the US rather than actually speaking the truth. However I would like to once and for all settle this, because I have seen various sites which also claim that the leaked documents in question are on Wikileaks, but I have not been able to find them there.

So is this the only proof for Snowden having leaked documents on aliens or are they on Wikileaks or somewhere else?

Comment: Youtube clip of Fox News show quoting Washington Post *blog* quoting Iranian FARS news agency.... it'd be better if original Farsi source for the claim was known to know exactly what the claim is.

Comment: This is likely from FARS' English website, which sometimes reprints articles from English language hoax blogs.

Comment: Given the political climate, and that fact that I can't access the link through work firewall, are we talking about aliens as in citizenship status, or Area 51 ET aliens?

Comment: @PoloHoleSet ET aliens, specifically "tall whites"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[forbes](https://www.forbes.com/sites/michaelpeck/2014/01/13/iran-says-tall-white-space-aliens-control-america/) says that this [whatdoesitmean.com](http://www.whatdoesitmean.com/index1730.htm) article is the original source.

As @user5341 said, Fox News and most other sources refer to FARS. The [fars](http://en.farsnews.com/newstext.aspx?nn=13921021000393) article is available online and indeed refers to whatdoesitmean.com. Fars also added a rather long disclaimer, saying that they are not reliable for the authenticity of the article.

whatdoesitmean.com say that their source is a Federal Security Services report, but they do not link the report, and a search for the supposed quotes from that report returns nothing. whatdoesitmean.com has been [described](https://www.vice.com/en_ca/article/an-iranian-news-agency-claims-america-is-run-by-nazi-space-aliens) as "a crackpot news site" [and](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2014/01/23/snowden-documents-us-alien-nazi-link_n_4592101.html) an "ultra-fringe conspiracy theory website".

So there seems to be no evidence that Snowden leaked documents regarding aliens.

Comment: What does mean FSB?

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave [Federal Security Service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_Security_Service) (FSB) is a Russian security agency.